# android accurate gps. calculate steps taken

Tags: android, gps

the app i am creating need to use gps to keep track of how many steps the user steps has taken during excercise. if i cannot count the steps at least i wanted to calculated very accurate distance.

my code can display a map and user location as a blue dot. it did follow me but is quite inaccurate sometimes.i can get the gps to get the current location but it is not very accurate. i heard there is a new location API but i could not find an example code. i can't spot the difference between them..

the following has a lot of code that is unnecessary the reason is i decided to not include the map.
my map api v2 cannot display on emulator. blue-stack displayed a blank map and cannot enter location data. i need to use the same emulator as my team. and i know that map is not a requirement but gps calculate steps/accurate distance is a requirement.

```
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, Runnable,     TextWatcher{

protected LocationManager locationManager;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
Button btnStartMove,btnPause,btnResume,btnStop;
//TextView Distance;
static double n=0;
    Long s1,r1;
    double lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2;
    double dis=0.0;
    MyCount counter;
    Thread t1;
    EditText userNumberInput;
    boolean bool=false;
    int count=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(isGooglePlay())
    {
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
    btnStartMove=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Start);//start moving
    btnPause=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Pause);//pause
    btnResume=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Resume);//resume
    btnStop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Stop);
    userNumberInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.UserInput);
    userNumberInput.addTextChangedListener(this);
    //Distance=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Distance);
    btnStartMove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //start(v);

            //start(v);
    }

    });
    btnPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //start(v); 
        }
    });
    btnResume.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //start(v); 
        }
    });
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //start(v); 
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    try
    {
        int no = Integer.parseInt(editable.toString());
        if(no >= 100)
        {
            editable.replace(0, editable.length(), "99");
        }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){}
}



@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if(googleMap == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Getting map",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        googleMap =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.displayMap)).getMap();

        if(googleMap != null)
        {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }

}

private void setUpMap() 
{
    //Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //Get locationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    //Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if(provider == null)
    {
        onProviderDisabled(provider);
    }
    //set map type
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    //Get current location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if(myLocation != null)
    {
        onLocationChanged(myLocation);
    }       
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
}

private boolean isGooglePlay() 
{
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Play Services is available",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return(true);
    }
    else
    {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 10).show();

    }
    return (false);

 }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location myLocation) {
    //Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    //Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
    //Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    //Show the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    //Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void start (View v){

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.Start:
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null)
        {
            lat2=location.getLatitude();
            lon2=location.getLongitude();
            bool=true;
            t1=new Thread(this);
            t1.start();
            counter= new MyCount(30000,1000);
            counter.start();

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "null location",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     break;
    case R.id.Pause:
        counter.cancel();
        bool=false;
        break;
    case R.id.Resume:
        counter= new MyCount(s1,1000);
     counter.start();
     bool=true;
     break;
//      case R.id.Distance:
//          double time=n*30+r1;
//          //Distance.setText("Distance:" + dis);
//          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"distance in  metres:"+String.valueOf(dis)+"Velocity in m/sec :"+String.valueOf(dis/time)+"Time :"+String.valueOf(time),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Value of Count:" + String.valueOf(count),
//                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//       break;        
    case R.id.Stop:
        counter.cancel();
        counter= new MyCount(30000,1000);
        bool = false;

    }
}

public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        counter= new MyCount(30000,1000);
     counter.start();
     n=n+1;
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        s1=millisUntilFinished;
        r1=(30000-s1)/1000;
        //e1.setText(String.valueOf(r1));


    }
}

public double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double latA = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    double lonA = Math.toRadians(lon1);
    double latB = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    double lonB = Math.toRadians(lon2);
    double cosAng = (Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonB-lonA)) +
                    (Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB));
    double ang = Math.acos(cosAng);
    double dist = ang *6371;
    return dist;
}

public static void distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)
{

}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    count=6;
    //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    lat1=location.getLatitude();
    lon1=location.getLongitude();
    while(bool==true)
    {
        if(lat1!=lat2 || lon1!=lon2)
        {
            dis+=getDistance(lat2,lon2,lat1,lon1);
            lat2=lat1;
            lon2=lon1;
            count =7;
            //Distance.setText("Distance: " + dis + " Count: " + count);
            count++;
        }

    }

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the distance, you can divide by the persons average step length, which you can let the user enter as paramter.

This will not work when making an exercise whithout moving (on a step trainer).
But for walking or running outdoors this will work.